# PDF.js not working when deploying to different Server in IE

Tags: javascript, pdf, sharepoint, pdf.js

I have a local IIS site where i developed some code with [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). There it worked fine to load a specific PDF and read the text contents from it.

Then I copied everything to the a library in a SharePoint Server (thats the only difference, IIS vs SharePoint) and changed all references. The code does not throw any Errors, with debugging level `info` it just prints

> Info: Cannot use postMessage Transfers

to the console. Adding a console.log line into the PDF.js catch block of the promise did not result in any new information. It doesn't even get to the first logging inside the `then`:

```
var pdfobj = PDFJS.getDocument(docPath);
pdfobj.then(function (pdf) {
  console.log(pdf);
```

any ideas?

EDITS: Updated from PDF.JS 1.1 to 1.2

There are not many error logs in PDF.js. I accidently hardcoded a wrong URL where even the server is non existent... and no error log, not even the `then(...).catch(...)` is called?

It is working now in Firefox but not in IE and I cannot see any reason for this. The Info message about `Cannot use postMessage Transfers` is also only displayed in IE (using IE 11).

Comment: Try turning on browser debugger ability to stop on any exception (even caught one). Can you mention any exception that it throws until it completely stops?

Comment: The only thing that was PDFJS related was this:
8291: var pdfJsSrc = document.currentScript.src;
  currentscript null
(and a million jquery exceptions). After setting the workerSrc this was fixed. So now there is no exception on no idea on why it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work now. I am not sure what I did to fix it, but I will update this answer when I know. I think it has something to do with the directory structure of the PDF.js files. Previously I just uploaded all JS files (there were no errors though).

Still there is no exception handling when the PDF does not exist.